# Fixing the "MSVCP110D.dll is missing from your computer" issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am facing the following (fairly common) problem: I am running my program in Debug mode in VS2010 and/or VS2012, but at startup it crashes, saying:

> The programme can't start because MSVCP100D.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Now I found a number of possible solutions, but none of them work for me:

- **Compile with /MTd instead of /MDd**: actually this does solve the problem, but I am not allowed to: my program is part of a bigger program, and /MD[d] is mandatory.
- **Install the [VS 2010 Redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632)**: This doesn't work because I have VS 2012 installed, so this installer tells me: "A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine."
- **Finding, dragging and dropping a version of MSVCP100D.dll into the correct directory**: I am not dropping unknown DLLs into places where they might interfere with other things.
- **Last resort: reinstalling VS2010/VS2012**: possible, but as it would also mean reinstalling lots of other packages and plugins I need, I'd like to avoid this if it's not absolutely necessary.

Are there any other options left?

Comment: Compile with /MD instead of /MDd.  Unlikely to have any effect since you don't appear to have VS2010 installed.  Which is what is required to get that file.  Or you lost it, somehow.  Copy it from another machine.  The 32-bit version goes in c:\windows\syswow64, the 64-bit version goes in c:\windows\system32.  Do this *after* checking the disk on the machine, losing files is never a good sign.

Answer (score 12):

The Visual Studio REDIST packages never deploy the DEBUG versions of the CRT files. This is *by design*.

With VS 2012 or later, the easiest way to deploy the DEUBG versions of the CRT is to install the "Remote Debugging Tools" package on your test machines.

For VS 2012, the latest Remote Debugging Tools package is [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255953)

For VS 2013, the latest Remote Debugging Tools package is [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402291).

Another option is to just use application local deployment of the DLL (i.e. copy it into your app directory). Again **this is only for testing purposes**. For actual deployment of your application, you are required to use the non-debug versions of the CRT.

If this error is happening on your development machine, however, then you have other problems because with VS 2012 installed, you should have the VS 2012 DEBUG CRT on that machine.

**UPDATE::** Sorry, I would have expected the debug CRT DLLs to be included in the remote debugging tools package along with the remote debugger bits and the Direct3D 11 Debug Device. Alas, it's not. See [Preparing a Test Machine To Run a Debug Executable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618(v=vs.110).aspx). You have to either use the MSMs in `Program Files (x86) directory in \Common Files\Merge Modules` or copy the DLL-side-by-side from `Program Files (x86) directory in \Microsoft Visual Studio <version>\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\`. The VS Team probably assumed you would have already been doing that, but I'll suggest to them to roll it into the remote tools package.

Comment: Well, no. Installing VS 2012 Remote Debugging Tools does not install  MSVCP100D.dll and does not fix the problem.

Comment: ``MSVCP100D.DLL`` is the VS 2010 CRT. Do you mean ``MSVCP110D.DLL``?

Comment: Yes, sorry. A typo. I'm getting error messages about missing `MSVCP110D.DLL`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (the project made in VS 2012 but I was running VS2013) and resolved it by:

1. Open the project (or the solution ) in VS2013(or the newer one)
2. Open Project menu and select "Retarget the project" option (it was the first option but after applying it, this option vanished).
3. Rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to openCV and C++ and had the same problem using openCV 2.4.10 with Visual Studio Express 2013 on a Windows 7, 32-bit platform. If I made a simple program without using OpenCV, the program ran but when I used OpenCV I got the missing DLL error.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df581872-ed1d-4d37-af39-c158da930e65/visual-studio-2012-with-opencv-win32-console-application?forum=vsdebug) made things clear:

I guess the problem I had was not with my Visual Studio but my OpenCV. The OpenCV was compiled on a version of visual studio which required MSVCP110.dll. I could have tried another version of OpenCV or compiled OpenCV again using VS2013 but I was short of time. Instead, I found the dll file elsewhere and placed it in my system32 folder (not sure if that's recommended). This fixed the problem. However as @slater mentioned, I won't recommend downloading the dll from external website due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a debug runtime DLL. If (and ONLY if!) you just want to run the debug build of your own application on a system without Visual Studio installed, then you can find the missing DLLs in

- `C:\Windows\System32` (for 64-bit builds)
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (for 32-bit builds)

Just keep copying DLLs until your executable will run.

If this is NOT what you are trying to do, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386721/2279059, which is the CORRECT, but less practical answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, I found out that the cause is that I used dll compiled with VS2012 in a VS2013 project. JUST downloaded the missing dll and put it in my linker path and wala: the program worked. I downloaded it from http://www.dll-files.com/.

Particulars: My program was working in in release mode but not in the debug mode as it says the  MSVCP110D.dll is missing. My code was an opencv image processing program. I put the missing dll in opencv linker path in the VS2013 project options.

Comment: Good diagnosis, bad solution. I recommend AGAINST using a download site.

Comment: Don't ever download C++ runtime DLLs from third-party sites, and don't ever recommend it to others. Don't ever google for DLLs. This is dangerous!

Comment: As said multiple times, it is very difficult to find reliable third-party websites that collect particular dlls. Correct me if I'm wrong of course. \n These are/would be overrun among a huge swarm of phony websites, even youtube channels, that let you download a corrupted dll and have you register it yourself.