# Can't run application on PC without visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I developed a game using visual studio 2015, done using c++ and opneGL with these libraries: `GLEW, GLFW, ASSIMP, IRRKLANG`.

It works fine on my PC and on Pcs of friends that have visual studio on their PCs but it cannot be start on other PCs.
I downloaded redistributables and I always get the same error which is msvcp140d.dll not found or something like that.

I tried to manual download it anf then the error changes until I can't download anything else.

I read that I had to change a setting in visual studio: change Runtime libraries from MD to MT but I still got the same problem.

Anyone knows what I can do?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You're trying to run the debug version so either provide the debug dlls or run the release build

Comment: I'm compiling it in release x86

Comment: No, the application is moaning about the debug dlls which are not part of the redistributable so either provide the debug dlls or compile the release version related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458908/fixing-the-msvcp110d-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-issue

Comment: I would check that all the projects of your solution and all the libraries you are linking are Release mode

Comment: My solution has just one project and it is compiled in release, how can I check if all my libraries are compiled in release mode?

Comment: @ScazzoMatto Get [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), load your executable into that program and look for Microsoft runtime DLL's that end with `D` in the file name (like `msvcp140D.dll`).  If you find any, this means you did not build a release version.

Comment: I've got that error but when I click on project preferences it says Configuration : Release, platform Win32

Comment: A Configuration is just a name.  Please go deeper into your project settings and ensure that the runtime library being used is Multithread or Multithread DLL.

Comment: already checked, now it's /MD and I already tried both /MD and /MT